# compile cdrtools with mingw

Tags: c++, mingw

I need to compile [cdrtools](http://cdrecord.berlios.de/private/cdrecord.html) with mingw (to avoid cygwin dependancy).

It was done somehow long time ago but sources are not available anymore:
http://web.archive.org/web/20040707140819/http://cdrtools.bootcd.ru/

Does anyone know how to compile cdrtools with mingw?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These so called "forks" both have less functionality than the original software but they are full of bugs and dead since many years.

dvdrtools started with a cdrtools version from 2001 (now 12 years old), removed the original DVD support code and replaced that by something that may work with a Pioneer A03. It did not destroy portability so it compiles on Win-DOS as cdrtools from 2001 do.

wodim uses a cdrtools version from September 2004 and did the same for the dvd support code but in addition destroyed the portability framework and added own specific bugs.

Cdrtools compile and work on Win-Dos since aprox. y1998.

To compile on Win-Dos, you need a cygwin environment and "smake" (gmake has bugs that prevent it from working correctly on that platform).

On such an environment, you may compile for cygwin and even using cl.exe. If you use cl.exe to compile, you will not get a working mkisofs due to intended non-POSIX compliance of the compile enviroment from Microsoft (struct stat always contains st_ino == 0, telling mkisofs that all files are hardlinked together).

There was a working mingw compile several years ago, but it seems that the instructions in READMEs/README.mingw32 no longer apply.

There has been a DJGPP compile aprox. 10 years ago (see READMEs/README.msdos) but this is also no longer correct for current DJGPP releases.

Answer (score 1):

cdrtools has been forked into [cdrkit](http://www.cdrkit.org/) and [dvdrtools](http://freshmeat.net/projects/dvdrtools/)

Both of these have the same (or greater) functionality so you might be better to attempt to compile them instead.

The prior seems to have a [patch on a mailing list](http://lists.alioth.debian.org/pipermail/debburn-devel/2009-July/000647.html) to allow it to be compiled on Windows. Give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

dvdrtools is dead since y2001 and represents just the first 4 years
of cdrtools development.

cdrkit is based on a cdrtools version from September 2004 and 
the cdrkit project did never develop any own code.

As a result, even cdrkit only offers aprox. 40% of the features
found in the original project. Given the fact that there are more
that 100 well documented bugs in cdrkit, it is a waste of time 
to look at these two pseudo projects.